# Is there an integer matrix with distinct entries and more than 2 rows with the property that every row sum is equal to every column product?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

Is there an integer matrix with distinct entries and more than 2 rows with the property that every row sum is equal to every column product?

The matrix below has every row sum = 840 and every column product = 840, but it only has 2 rows.
\begin{bmatrix}2&4&7&24&40&70&105&140&168&280\\420&210&120&35&21&12&8&6&5&3\end{bmatrix}

https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1102.html

Comment: In your site it says that you have two proofs of existence. None of them are constructive?

Comment: The proofs are that matrices exist of all sizes with the same row sum and same column product, but not necessarily that those sum and product are equal to each other.

Comment: Thankyou for that link.  I thought we had lost them.

Comment: This is interesting. I feel like you just need to choose a big enough highly composite number for the product (I don't think 5040 is big enough) and you can probably get it to work out. But the size of the number needed is such that searching for the matrix might require insight to be targeted/efficient enough.